# Array out of bounds exception:

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to recieve bluetooth messages and my app runs but then after some time (1min or so)I get an array out of bounds exception on the read buffer, also it doesn't seem to be reading my message and updating my textview?

```
void beginListenForData()
{
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

stopWorker = false;
readBufferPosition = 0;
readBuffer = new byte[1024];
workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
        {
            try
            {
                int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                {
                    byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                    mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                    for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                    {
                        byte b = packetBytes[i];
                        if(b == delimiter)
                        {
                            byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                            System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                            final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                            readBufferPosition = 0;

                            handler.post(new Runnable()
                            {
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    myLabel.setText(data);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                stopWorker = true;
            }
        }
    }
});

workerThread.start();
```

}

Comment: because your array size is 1024, and when readBufferPosition exceeds its size you get exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an Array with 1024 max number of cells.

1) Increase the number size of the `Array`. (But you can get this exception again if it will be too small again).

2) Use a `List` instead the `Array`, the items will be added to the list without max size an the list will increase until the method will be finished, and you won't get the "OutOfBoundException".